# Modifying column: Foreign key "onDelete()" property changing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I need to change property of a table column. In my first migration I defined the table as

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('mark');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Now I want to add *onDelete('cascade')* to the foreign-key column. Then I have created another table to define it

```
class ChangeForeignkyeQuestionsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->change();
        });
    }
}
```

After running the following command, I got error.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Error message is :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mypollapp`.`questions` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `questions` add constraint `questions_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mypollapp`.`questions` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")")
      E:\Pervez\Tech\htdocs\mypollapp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:123

2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mypollapp`.`questions` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")")
      E:\Pervez\Tech\htdocs\mypollapp\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:121
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "change" syntax in MySql for foreign keys. The best way to handle your situation is to drop the foreign key and recreate it.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->change();
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->change();
    });
}
```